# Using rc.local to start server and then launch web-application?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm running into issues when I try to start a server via Python program, and then open its web-app. I'm not able to get it to open the server and then also open the web-application.

I tried to modify `rc.local` to the following before exit 0:

```
sudo python /home/pi/Program/program.py &
sudo bash chromium-browser --kiosk https://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

I also tried to use `bashrc` to do this, but while I was able to run server on bootup with `rc.local`, I wasn't able to run it with `bashrc` on bootup. Only once I run LXTerminal was it able to open the server. On `rc.local`, the opposite problem. Can run server but not browser.

I am able to boot the python program on its own, and the webpage on its own (but obviously it gives address not found, since there is no server), but not the two together.

I tried to modify rc local to bin/sh -e but this didn't work still.

I am running Rasbian Os.

I am unable to work with what was said in the post that was suppose to answer my question. The answer only tells you what you should be doing, which is what I already know, start the browser after GUI, but it doesn't tell me how to do it. It also doesn't solve my problem of the server having to be up and running before I start the browser. May I also mention how I tried many methods but none of them worked... I tried to edit autostart as well bashrc.

Comment: I'd do it more like this - https://obrienlabs.net/setup-raspberry-pi-kiosk-chromium/

Answer (score 1):

And here I am answering my own question because everyone is so quick to say duplicate... except that it wasnt the right duplicate.

I was looking for this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40631/setting-up-a-kiosk-with-chromium/40745#40745?newreg=c9704e6834f541ffb621ede086bdccc2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run any X application from `rc.local`, you have to define which display you're using since `rc.local` doesn't execute commands within your normal shell environment.

First of all detect which display is being used in your system:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

The output will be something like this:

```
:0.0
```

or

```
:1
```

Let's assume your `DISPLAY` variable is `:1`, then add before command with GUI application `DISPLAY=:1`, i.e.:

```
python /home/pi/Program/program.py &
DISPLAY=:1 chromium-browser --kiosk https://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

And, of course, remove `sudo` since `rc.local` is being executed from `root` user. Remove `bash` before `chromium-browser` too.

Consider to run `chromium-browser` as ordinary user. Let's assume your user name is `bob`, then replace your command with:

```
DISPLAY=:1 sudo -u bob chromium-browser --kiosk https://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

Replace `bob` with your real user name.